# Drawing directly on personal wiki

Tags: wiki

Is there any existing wiki support direct drawing function?

Perhaps it is not a good idea for a well formatted wiki, how about a personal one?

People nowadays using finger(tablet) or pens much often than keyboard,
a **quick sketching** is sometimes much easier to describing concept.

(import picture sounds not a lazy solution)

Thanks!

Comment: You might check out FreeMind (http://freemind.sourceforge.net/), it's not a wiki tool but a mind mapping one, which lets you create objects and organize and tag them visually. Maybe you could build some framework which adds a visual design component as a new wiki feature?

Comment: Thanks Darth. Mind map is sometime too much for me. Actually, some text with few sketching is already good. You are right, I am looking for a plugin or component for a wiki feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twiki](http://twiki.org/) has a [TWikiDraw Plugin](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Plugins/TWikiDrawPlugin), which is also supported under [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/PmWikiDraw). There's also an experimental extension for [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) called [AnyWikiDraw](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAnyWikiDraw). I suspect there are more, but those should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It's good to see some solutions, maybe the drawing idea is not very popular.

Answer (score 0):

Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware has integrated the awesome SVG-edit as a built-in feature, with integrated permissions and versioning. (so it's not just for a personal wiki)

- http://doc.tiki.org/Draw
- http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

MediaWiki, DokuWiki, XWiki, MoinMoin, TiddlyWiki (and likely others) have it available as a plugin/extension.

M ;-)